# How to add cloudinary file as email attachment in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am building a job application in Rails and I need to attach resumes(cv) that are uploaded in a job application as an email attachment. All files in the application are uploaded to Cloudinary using CarrierWave. Emails are handled by Action Mailer. In ActionMailer, I have

```
  class ApplicantMailer < ApplicationMailer    
      def applicant_info(applicant)
        @applicant = applicant
        mail(to: @applicant.job.email, subject: 'Applicant Details')
      end
   end
```

In my mailer view template, I have

```
<p>Hi Recruiter, in this email, you would find the resume of the latest applicant</p>
<p>Resume: <%= cl_image_tag(@applicant.resume, :attachment=>true) %></p>
```

At the moment, this does not render the cloudinary file as an attachment in the email. I need to be able to render the resume as a readable attachment file.

Comment: what do we expect `@applicant.resume` to return? Also, what error messages do you get with your current code?

Comment: @applicant.resume return the url to download the file from cloudinary. The current code send the email just fine but the @applicant.resume(resume) is not an attachment in the email. But i want it to be an attachment

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I don't think you need that helper

```
class ApplicantMailer < ApplicationMailer    
  def applicant_info(applicant)
    @applicant = applicant
    attachments[ open(applicant.resume) ]
    mail(to: @applicant.job.email, subject: 'Applicant Details')
  end
 end
```

#### template

```
<p>Hi Recruiter, in this email, you would find the resume of the latest applicant</p>
<p>Resume: <%= image_tag @applicant.resume %></p>
```

Comment: it is not working. I get the following error "no implicit conversion of ResumeUploader into String"

Comment: hard to tell without seeing full stack trace but what happens if your remove `<p>Resume: <%= image_tag @applicant.resume %></p>` does the email work and attach the file? If not, I suspect `@applicant.resume` is not what you think it is. What type of object is `@applicant` and is `.resume` a method? a relation? We can only guess with the info you've provided.

Comment: @applicant is an instance variable of the model Applicant and .resume is a Carrierwave object that is a column field in the Applicant model.

Comment: update your question to show related code in Applicant model and add full stack trace of your errors.